Flutter BLoC and immutable state
Sometimes a BLoC state includes multiple fields and we need a separate class to store the bloc state. In the examples the approach is used that the state is an immutable object, and to change the state we need to perform a complete copy of the state object:
emit(state.copyWith(status: WeatherStatus.loading));

The question is why do we need to make the state class immutable and isn't this an unnecessary copy operation leading to insufficient code efficiency?

The practice of making state classes immutable in the context of BLoC pattern in Flutter, and using methods like copyWith to emit new states, is rooted in several principles of good software design, especially for state management in reactive programming.
The worry that copying an object to update a single field is inefficient might be valid in scenarios where performance is critical, and the objects are large or complex. However, in the vast majority of Flutter apps the performance impact is negligible.
Also, it brings readability, simplicity, and maintainability to update the state by using copyWith method.
I call mutable state "the pirate block".
